# Find directories and merge files

Tags: find, cat

So I have a file system of thousands of subdirectories in the form

```plain
304880.US
906T89.DE
032848.UK
023455.UKREGRESS
:
```

Sometimes inside the folders there are other folders called `1`, `2` and `3`.

Each end-directory contain various text files and among them `output.txt`.

I want to find all the directories which has `.UK` anywhere in the name and merge all of their `output.txt` files into one master file. Order does not matter.

Example:

```
├── 032848.UK
│   ├── corrupted.txt
│   ├── errors.txt
│   ├── notfound.txt
│   ├── output.txt
│   └── rejected.txt
├── 135411.UK
│   ├── 1
│   │   ├── corrupted.txt
│   │   ├── errors.txt
│   │   ├── notfound.txt
│   │   ├── output.txt
│   │   └── rejected.txt
│   ├── 2
│   │   ├── corrupted.txt
│   │   ├── errors.txt
│   │   ├── notfound.txt
│   │   ├── output.txt
│   │   └── rejected.txt
│   └── 3
│       ├── corrupted.txt
│       ├── errors.txt
│       ├── notfound.txt
│       ├── output.txt
│       └── rejected.txt
├── 304880.US
│   ├── corrupted.txt
│   ├── errors.txt
│   ├── notfound.txt
│   ├── output.txt
│   └── rejected.txt
├── 906T89.DE
│   ├── corrupted.txt
:   :
└── ...
```

Comment: I mean .UK anywhere. The files in 1, 2, and 3 also. No, if a folder is divided between 1, 2, and 3 there is no output.txt in the root folder. Order does not matter. The code wouldn't suffice because there files in each directory other than output.txt; i.e. there is also errors.txt, rejected.txt, notfound.txt, and corrupted.txt

Comment: Sorry if I can't explain it properly @ibuprofen I've never used bash before

Comment: Find all subdirectories named *.UK: `find . -type d -name '*.UK'`. Use that list to `cat [123]/output.txt`. Redirect the output to a new file.

Comment: Your filesystem is in a total mess! If you succeed with this problem, the next one will defeat you!

Comment: Merge meant concatenation?

Comment: *“I've never used bash before”* – It is not about that. It is about explaining the situation with enough detail for people to be able to help find a solution. I did an edit and hope it is correct. If you have additional information please *edit question*. Information *relevant to the question* should be in the question not in comments.

Comment: Reading over it again it is still a few things that are unclear: 1) Merge or concatenate? 2) Does the folders (beside the 1, 2, and 3) reside in the same directory? 3) Do you want to a) merge/concatenate *all* the files into *one* – or b) the ones in the sub-directories 1, 2 and 3 into one for each folder named something with `UK`?

Answer (score 1):

*(f assuming merge is concatenate.)*

## Concatenate

You could do something like this (**find**):

```matlab
find . -wholename '*.UK*/*output.txt' -exec cat {} >>concatenated.UK.txt +
```

or by globing:

```matlab
cat *.UK*/*{output.txt,/output.txt} >concatenated.UK.txt
```

or to be more specific:

```matlab
cat *.UK*/{output.txt,[123]/output.txt} >concatenated.UK.txt
```

---

## List

As for find, you can see what it find by:

```matlab
find . -wholename '*.UK*/*output.txt'
```

And for the globs e.g.:

```sh
printf '%s\n' *.UK*/{output.txt,[123]/output.txt}
```

Answer (score 0):

I proceed from the condition - merge means concatenation. And the resulting file should be placed in the directory `*.UK/`:

```bsh
find -path '*.UK/[123]/output.txt' -exec bash -c 'cat $0 >>${0%/*}/../output.txt' {} \;
```

You can add a path like this:
`\( -path '*.UK/[123]/output.txt' -o -path '*.UKREGRESS/[123]/output.txt' \)`
But the resulting file will each be placed in its own parent directory.